# Showing that if $K$ is a splitting field of $f(x)\in F[x]$ over $F$, then $[K:F]\leq n!$

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

I have a field $F$ and a polynomial $f(x)\in F[x]$  of degree $n$ and $K$ a splitting extension field of $f(x)$ over $F$, and I want to show that $[K:F]\leq n!$ My attempt is:

Of course, if $u_1,\dots,u_n$ are the roots of $f(x)$ then $K=F(u_1,\dots,u_n)$. Let try by induction over $n$. If $n=1$ then of course $K=F$ and we have nothing to do. Suppose that the result is true for $n-1$ and take $f(x)\in F[x]$ of degree $n$. Then in $K=F(u_1,\dots,u_n)$, $f(x)$ takes the form $f(x)=a(x-u_1)\cdots(x-u_n)=(x-u_1)g(x)$ for some $g(x)\in K[x]$ But of course $g(x)$ have degree $n-1$ and its splitting field is $G=F(u_2,\dots,u_n)$, so by the induction hypotesis we have $[G:F]\leq (n-1)!$ But note that $K=G(u_1)$, and since $u_1$ is a root of $f(x)$ its minimal polynomial over $F$ has degree $\leq n$, but then since $F\subset G$ we have that $[G(u_1):G]\leq n$ because the minimal polynomial of $u_1$ over $G$ divides $f(x)$. Therefore $[K:F]=[G(u_1):G][G:F]\leq n!$ .

Now I'm not really confident about my solution, and I want that someone take a look and give me a feedback, thanks!

Comment: Isn't it the case that any automorphism of $K$ that fixes $F$ is determined by its values on the roots of $f$?  Because from that, it follows that the Galois group of $K/F$ embeds into $S_n$, which tells you $[K:F] \leq n!$.

Comment: I haven't studied Galois yet

Comment: This place in your proof is not very clear so by the induction hypothesis we have $[G:F]\leq(n-1)!$ 
You should first check that the field $G$ is a splitting extension field of a polynomial from $F[x]$ of degree less than $n$.